# xml documentation file of nuget dependencies not part of publish - .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, nuget, swashbuckle, xml-documentation, dotnet-cli

I have a project which is referring packages from nuget. These packages from nuget have their XML documentation file included as part of the package (present in `.nupkg` file at `/lib/netstandard2.0/<projectName>.xml` along with `<projectName>.dll` file)

The XML documentation file is getting generated by adding below in `csproj` file:

```
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```

Now when I am publishing the project which has these nuget packages references, the xml documenation file of the referred nuget packages is not becoming part of publish.

It seems this is an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795).

Is there a workaround to include xml documentation of referred packages ?

Answer (score 2):

Found a [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-420456386) which is making this work. Added below in the `.csproj' file:

```
 <Target Name="_ResolvePublishNuGetPackagePdbsAndXml"
        AfterTargets="RunResolvePublishAssemblies">
  <ItemGroup>
      <ResolvedFileToPublish 
        Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')" 
        RelativePath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.pdb'))"
        DestinationSubPath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.pdb'))"
        Condition="'%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.PackageName)' != ''
                    and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish 
        Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" 
        RelativePath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.xml'))"
        DestinationSubPath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.xml'))"
        Condition="'%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.PackageName)' != ''
                    and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

It will make xml (and pdb if present) files of referred packages become part of published files.